# Python 3 create error if user input is not an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below working the way I want it to.
How do I add an error if the user does not enter an integer?

```
userdata = input("Input the number of numbers to be stored :")

userNumz = []          

print("Input " + str(userdata) + " numbers :")  
for index in range(int(userdata)):
    userNumz.append(input(str(index) + " is "))
```

I have tried to use `ValueError` but can't get it to work . My attempt below:

```
while True
    try:
        userdata = input("Input the number of numbers to be stored :")
    except ValueError:
        print("The input was not a valid integer.)
```

Comment: The user **does not ever** enter an integer, **even if** it consists of all digit symbols.

Answer (score 4):

If you cast the input as `int` then it will throw the error you want:

```
while True
    try:
        userdata = int(input("Input the number of numbers to be stored :"))
    except ValueError:
        print("The input was not a valid integer.)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Code:

To invoke an error on an invalid conversion try:

```
userdata = int(userdata)
```

#### In Context:

```
while True
    try:
        userdata = input("Input the number of numbers to be stored :")
        userdata = int(userdata)
    except ValueError:
        print("The input was not a valid integer.)
```

Answer (score 1):

User input will be a string, so when you try to convert it to an int you'll get a ValueError if the user gave you a letter or word.

```
def get_int():
    userdata = input("Enter an int, or 'q' to quit: ")
    if userdata == 'q':
        return None
    try:
        user_num = int(userdata)
        return user_num
    except ValueError:
        print("I need an integer to continue.")
        return(get_int())

user_number = get_int()
```

This function will loop until the user enters an int or quits with a 'q'. The following lines would deal with the returned number (or the `None` object if they quit).